# Moving the placeholder text from inside of the input to be above the input field

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm attempting to move the placeholder="Gift Recipient's First Name" to above the input field on focus. I'm using gravity forms and the below HTML is how the placeholder is being displayed. Is there anyway I can move it above the field so that once someone starts typing it doesn't go away?

```html
<li id="field_33_9"
    class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible">
    <label class="gfield_label" for="input_33_9">
        Gift Recipient's First Name<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
    <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text">
        <input name="input_9" id="input_33_9" type="text" value="" class="medium"
            placeholder="Gift Recipient's First Name*" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" />
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Not my work but take a look at this codepen for inspiration: https://codepen.io/uncommonjoe/pen/wxvXXZ

Basically the trick is to use a styled and positioned `label` rather than an actual `placeholder`

Comment: Thanks Jack! I'll look into it. I appreciate you and your time!